# click event not call event after load `<a href="#">btn</a>` with `ajax`

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that loaded with ajax complete,
I have buttons on the page (load with ajax), so I want after click the button run an alert event,
I try `bind`,`delegate`,`live`,`on` Event to attach the Event to handler but no result.
I'm try add test btn manually and that call the event but the buttons that load via ajax not call Event.
My html code:

```
<body>
<a href='#' class='insert_cm'>test btn</a>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="rightmenu"></div>
<div class="content">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

my `JQuery` code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".header").load("header.html");
    $(".rightmenu").load("sidebar.html");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'timeline.php',
        success:function(data){
            $(".content").html(data);

            }
        });
            //insert comment after click the cm-btn
    $( ".insert_cm" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
        })

    });
```

and the `php` code:

```
<?php
include('db_inc.php');
include("myfunc.php");
$functionId=$_POST[functionId];
switch($functionId){
    case "":
    $music_query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM music LIMIT 15") or die($connection->error);

            while($music = $music_query->fetch_array()){
                $music_id=$music['msuic_id'];
                $music_thumb =$music['music_thumb'];
                $music_name=$music['file_name'];
                echo "<div class='music-item'>
                <div class='music-avatar'>
                   <img src=admin/thumb/$music_thumb alt='avatar'>
                </div>
                <div class='music-post'>
                    <h3> $music_name <a href='#'  class='like_music' >لایک</a></h3>

                    <p> $music_composer </p>";
                    $comment_query=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM comments where f_music_id = '$music_id'") or die($connection->error);
                    while($comments = $comment_query->fetch_array()){
                        $username = get_username($comments['f_user_id']);
                        echo "
                        <div class='username_comment'>
                        <h4> $username <span>:</span></h4>
                        $comments[comment];
                        </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    echo "<textarea id='txt_cm' name='txt_cm'></textarea>
                    <a href='#' class='insert_cm'>insert comment</a>";
            }
}

?>
```

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using? Did you try `$( document ).on( "click",".insert_cm", func...`

Comment: my version is `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always use `$(document).on()` for dynamically created element if you want to bind an event to them.

```
$(document).on("click", ".insert_cm", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
    return false;
});
```

the event binder should sit on document level so that it recognize whenever there are more elements added to DOM

more info on $(document).on() : [Is it possible to capture keydown globally on dynamically added text inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613994/is-it-possible-to-capture-keydown-globally-on-dynamically-added-text-inputs/20614116#20614116)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click",".insert_cm",function() {
    alert("User clicked on 'foo.'");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with updated syntax in the jQuery version > 1.8:

```
$(".content").on( "click",".insert_cm", function() {
  alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
})
```

**Syntax:**

```
$(selector/Closest parent).on(event,target,function(){});
```

That is called *EventDelegation*!

Where `.content` reffers to the closest parent element, you can also use `document`, `document.body` too.